# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}x e^{-3x} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I just can't get the correct answer on this one. I know the method is right but my arithmetic blows upp somewhere, I can't see where.

Using partial integration, where I start by integrating $e^{-3x}$ I get

$$\int_{0}^{1}x e^{-3x} \ dx =-\frac{-xe^{-3x}}{3}+3\int e^{-3x} \ dx=\left[\frac{-xe^{-3x}}{3}-e^{-3x}\right]_{0}^{1} = \\ = \left[\left(-\frac{x}{3}-1\right)e^{-3x}\right]_{0}^{1}=\boxed{-\frac{4}{3e^3}-1}.$$

Correct answer: $$\boxed{-\frac{4}{9e^3}+\frac{1}{9}}$$

Comment: Where you have written $3$ you should have $\frac 13$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int\limits_0^1 xe^{-3x}dx = \frac{xe^{-3x}}{-3}|_0^1 - \int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-3x}}{-3}dx$

I think you took the derivative of $e^{-3x}$ instead of integrating it, your $3\int e^{-3x}dx$ should instead be $\frac{-1}{3}\int e^{-3x}dx$